# AWS SNS filter policy using AND and OR

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sns

I want to create a SNS filter policy for a single topic like this.
So event A has no tag, but event B C do.

```
{
  event = [
    "A",
  ],
},
{
  event = [
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  tags = [
    "tag"
  ],
}
```

But it doesn't seem like it supports multiple criteria like this fashion.
Is where a way to do this?

When I checked the documentation,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html#and-or-logic

It does not mention case where one use separate criterion using both OR and AND.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have example of TF code showing how would you want to use such filter policy?

Comment: I don't have one, as the code requires having two jsons. And I can't set 2 policy on single topic. When i try it on console:

"Couldn't create subscription.
Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Subscription already exists with different attributes"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, however, you can't do `AND/OR` with "[filter policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/and-or-logic.html)".

You will have to create multiple subscriptions with a different endpoint for each subscription.

Answer (score 0):

In November 2023, Amazon SNS added support for the 'OR' operator in the filter policy. More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/and-or-logic.html#or-operator

Standard OR:

```
{
  "source": [ "aws.cloudwatch" ], 
  "$or": [
    { "metricName": [ "CPUUtilization" ] },
    { "namespace": [ "AWS/EC2" ] }
  ] 
}
```

The filter logic for this policy is:

```
"source" && ("metricName" || "namespace")
```

It matches either of the following sets of message attributes:

```
"source": {"Type": "String", "Value": "aws.cloudwatch"},
"metricName": {"Type": "String", "Value": "CPUUtilization"}
```

or

```
"source": {"Type": "String", "Value": "aws.cloudwatch"},
"namespace": {"Type": "String", "Value": "AWS/EC2"}
```